# Anything similar to ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush in AngularJS 1?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there an equivalent to Angular's (v2+) `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` for AngularJS 1?

In other words, is there a way to restrict `$digest` cycles from re-evaluating scope inside certain components unless the component's `$onChanges` hook has just fired (meaning one of the bindings has been updated)? This could be built-in functionality into AngularJS or a third-party module.

Working with SPAs that have very large code bases (meaning it would take a year to upgrade to Angular2), it would certainly be nice to get some of those `OnPush` performance benefits today.